# How to save tweets from TweetStream with SQLite3 and Ruby

Tags: ruby, twitter, sqlite, save, tweetstream

I am very new to ruby and RoR. I would like to save incoming tweets that are currently being displayed on my terminal. Could you explain why the tweets are not being saved?

I run " ruby mine_tweets.rb" in the terminal and the the "puts" of the status.text appears, but there are no entries in the database.

## mine_tweets.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'tweetstream'


puts "searching for turkey....should write to database"

TweetStream.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key       = 'XXXXXXX'
  config.consumer_secret    = 'XXXXXXX'
  config.oauth_token        = 'XXXXXXX'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'XXXXXXX'
  config.auth_method        = :oauth
end

# search for "turkey" and will print text and screen name and should store other values in db
TweetStream::Client.new.track('turkey') do |status|
  puts status.text + " FROM: @" + status.user.screen_name   
  Tweet.create(:user_id => status.user.id, :tweet_text => status.text, :screen_name     =>status.user.screen_name)
  Tweet.save!

end

@client = TweetStream::Client.new

@client.on_delete do |status_id, user_id|
  Tweet.delete(status_id)
end
```

## model/tweets.rb

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :screen_name, :tweet_text, :user_id
end
```

Comment: Just so you know, it's against Twitters terms to save tweets to an external database for the purposes of "separate status update or social network database or service".

Comment: Hi Cyle, I am not trying to create a seperate status update or social network database. I would like to aggregate the data for something like 3d js geared towards musicians and music related things! But first things first... I need to know how to save the data.

Answer (score 0):

I recently struggled through this myself. Here is what I found:

In order to save to a database, you need to :

- create a database.
- connect application to db.
- create table and columns
- ..do something, ie. save, query etc.
- close connection (before exiting app)

Here is how i was able to save tweets from the Tweet Stream api into a sqlite local database. (I highly recommend switching directly to Postgres since Heroku doesn't support sqlite).

## tweetstream.rb

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'tweetstream'

KEY = 'xxx'
SECRET = 'xxx'
TOKEN = 'xxx'
TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxx'

SEARCH_TERMS = "your search terms"

begin

  db = SQLite3::Database.open "./db/tweets.db"
  db.execute "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store_tweets(
    id, INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    tweetid TEXT, 
    text TEXT, 
    screen_name TEXT,
    userid TEXT, 
    user_name TEXT, 
    profile_image_url TEXT,
    language,
    created_at TEXT, 
    received_at TIMESTAMPS)"

    TweetStream.configure do |config|
      config.consumer_key       = KEY
      config.consumer_secret    = SECRET
      config.oauth_token        = TOKEN
      config.oauth_token_secret = TOKEN_SECRET
      config.auth_method        = :oauth
    end

  TweetStream::Client.new.track(SEARCH_TERMS) do |status|
    puts "#{status.text}"
    db.execute( "INSERT INTO store_tweets(
      'tweetid', 
      'text', 
      'screen_name',
      'userid', 
      'user_name', 
      'profile_image_url',
      'language') 
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
      [status[:id]], 
      [status.text], 
      [status.user.screen_name],
      [status.user[:id]], 
      [status.user.name], 
      [status.user.profile_image_url],
      [status.lang])
  end

rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
  puts "Exception occured"
  puts e
ensure
  db.close if db
end
```